# Using Compass results in 404 Error

Tags: sass, compass

After I used SASS library Compass in my website project, the browser console starts to log 404 Error like this

```html
GET http://localhost:63342/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_animation.scss 404 (Not Found) index.html:44
GET http://localhost:63342/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/_support.scss 404 (Not Found) index.html:44
GET http://localhost:63342/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_transition.scss 404 (Not Found) index.html:44
GET http://localhost:63342/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_border-radius.scss 404 (Not Found) index.html:44
GET http://localhost:63342/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_box-shadow.scss 404 (Not Found)
```

What's going on? How could I eliminate those?

Comment: we need to see at least your markup code. Also, it'd be useful to see the compass command(s) you run. It looks like you're trying to load some parials

Comment: Please note that there is a difference between a code-snippet and a code sample. A code (or stack) snippet is runnable. Code samples are not. The stuff you posted didn't contain runable javascript. Please visit the [help] to learn about our features.

Comment: You might want to check out Bundler to make sure you have a good local build for your project. http://bundler.io/

Comment: I found the cause. There's a ***.css.map file associates with a **.css file, after compressed sass. There's a JSON in this map file with a property "sources" : ["../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets/compass/css3/_animation.scss", ...]. But why will browser go for those map sources?